# ngspice installation error

Tags: juju

while trying to install ngspice it is showing this error

config.status: error: in `/home/farazrabbani/Downloads/ngspice-31/release':
config.status: error: Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments
    for automatic dependency tracking.  Try re-running configure with the
    '--disable-dependency-tracking' option to at least be able to build
    the package (albeit without support for automatic dependency tracking).
See`config.log' for more details

i tried to find solution from various sites,but i couldnt

Kindly help me.

Comment: If you are inexperienced with building software from source, please note that `ngspice` is available directly from the Ubuntu repositories (in `multiverse` for Bionic and in `universe` for Eoan)

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need to compile NGSpice from source.

It is available from official [*multiverse* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ngspice). To install do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ngspice
```

If you need to compile it from source - enable Source code repositories in Software & Updates and then get build-dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ngspice
```

and then continue the compilation process as you planned.

Comment: Does it install complete version of ngspice.Because I have previously installed ngspice through terminal in Kali Linux.it only installs a lite version of ngspice which doesn't satisfy my needs

Comment: However i have installed as you said but it doesn't install complete version

Comment: sorry but it is showing some error  "You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list"
kindly help...

Comment: You need to open Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and check *Source Code* checkmark, then confirm reloading package caches.

Comment: yes its working thanku soo much bro